# How to segregate python pages in flask and mysql?

Tags: python, flask, modularization

I am beginner working on flask and mysql all my python code are in one single page in app.py but i no that this is not the correct way in flask and sqlalchamey they divide the pages into **init**.py, views.py, auth.py, main.py .writing python code in single page may leads to problem in loading pages.Is there any ways to divide py pages using flask and mysql.

writing code in different python page try to import that pages in app.py ,worked on add_url_rule nothing is working.My project is little bit big so try to divide pages.